Matrix Free alternatives in dealii
I am implementing a Fast Multipole Method (FMM) in deal ii.
I do not want to store a dense matrix, but lower rank matrices and to use matrix free methods. By now, I store the elements of the low-rank matrices, and I want to retrieve them to compute the action of the operator in a vector.
What is the easiest way to implement a matrix free solver with GMRES (non-symmetric matrix)?
I have considered the MatrixFree class and also the Trilinos Wrapper. However, the MatrixFree class seems to be implemented for parallel computing the elements of the matrix on the fly (I am happy with a look-up table), and Trilinos is a bit scary for me (I can try if no other option). Am I forced to use parallel computing to get access to Matrix Free algorithms in deal ii?
======= EDIT ====
As Julian Roth suggested in the comments, I posted the question in the deal ii forum, and I got an answer from Luca Heltai.
He recommends using the LinearOperator class.
Concerning FMM, he pointed out that a FMM program has already been implemented in deal ii (pi-BEM), so I can draw inspiration from it.

I would ask this question on the deal.II forum (https://groups.google.com/g/dealii) for deal.II specific questions.
